# Validation of date input into textbox when using JQueryUI Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have a textbox that I've attached the datepicker to. If the user enters the date via the datepicker all is well but they also have the ability to go in and enter a bad date directly into the textbox. i.e. 1/55/1995
Can the text box be disabled so only the calendar can be used?

How are people preventing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you need is to just disable the field or make it readonly.  Check out this answer [How can I disable all keyboard keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261325/how-can-i-disable-all-keyboard-keys)

I would say readonly is the better option because it still allows the value to be retrieved when it is posted back; don't think disabled fields get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the input text, if entered manually to the textbox.

Have a look at the url below,
http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html

Hope this helps.

Cheers