# How to disable all keyboard action in IE using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

How to disable all keyboard action in IE using JavaScript or jQuery?
I have tried all the keycode but didn't get the output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261325/how-can-i-disable-all-keyboard-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
$('html').bind('keypress', function(e)
{
   return false;
});
```

This will disable all keyboard events.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code you wrote in your file.